Part identification / explanation needed
I've got this rotary / precision potentiometer in a logitech g27 shifter and I can't find an exact replacement. I'd like to know what the writing means on it so I can find alternative solution.
Most importantly, I'd like to know what does the 0A means and if it's possible to substitute it with 8A.
This is the original part:


https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/927/252_Series.pdf  Obsolete sources require more details to replace like resistance and pitch

Thanks a ton for the datasheet! It helped a lot! Now I know that this is most likely a 10k resistance potentiometer.
The replacement part that I've found online is the cts 251s0096 which has the same letters and numbers but it has 8A printed on it instead of the 0A.
I'm still looking for what that actually means because I haven't found the datasheet of the 251s0096 yet but at least I'm getting closer.
